# c# copy/move into locked file/stream

Tags: c#, file, stream, locking

I need help in how to lock the file, copy it, modify copy, and save copy back to original file, while the original file remains locked.

Here is the current flow:
User opens the file, the application copies it into a temporary folder and locks the original file with the following line

```
_lockStream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
```

Then when it comes to save the temp file back to the original file, currently I am using the following routine (destination = _lockStream, and source = temp file's stream):

```
public static void Copy(Stream source, Stream destination, int bufferSize)
    {
        int readed = 0;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        destination.SetLength(source.Length);
        destination.Position = 0;

        while ((readed = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            destination.Write(buffer, 0, readed);
        }
        destination.Flush();
    }
```

I would prefer to use File.Copy instead, but I don't know how to make it working with locked file, even if file is locked by the application.
And, what's worse, my method it's not safe, if application or system crashes in the middle, the original file is corrupted. I think that more correct approach would be copy to the same folder, and then move (or just simply move) but I don't know how to do it retaining lock on the original file.

So, now to make it safe I release file lock, and use File.Copy, then obtain lock again. It works, but for some milliseconds the file is unlocked and can be locked by other processes.

What is best way of doing such things?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your method safe you can use TransactionScope like this:

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
{               
    Copy(source, destination, buffersize);
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: This does not work. When I stop in the copy method in debugger, and exit, the destination stream is partially overwritten.